# Define SQLAlchemy after_update as a method on a class

Tags: python, dependency-injection, sqlalchemy, decorator

I have tried

```
@event.listens_for(User, 'after_update')
def receive_after_update(self, mapper, connection, target):
    "listen for the 'after_update' event"
```

But it would fail with:

```
TypeError: receive_after_update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'target'
```

Is there a clever way to inject the dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Remove self from that function.

That should work.

```
@event.listens_for(User, 'after_update')
def receive_after_update(mapper, connection, target):
    "listen for the 'after_update' event"
```